# React - pre-populate form

Tags: forms, reactjs

I need to prepopulate a form so that users can edit a blog they have previously created.  I'm looking for the best-practices way of doing this in React. I am currently passing the value to a component through props, and then setting a state property to equal a props property, but I have read that this is an anti-pattern.  I understand 'source of truth'.  But what is a better way to do it?  I would rather not use redux-form, for now.  Below is my title component, and below that is how I call it from the parent.  This all works, but is there a better way, in order to avoid setting a state property to a props property?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class DocumentTitle extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {inputVal:this.props.publication.document_title}
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({inputVal: event.target.value});
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({inputVal: nextProps.publication.document_title})
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <div >
        <label>Title</label>
        <div>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} id="doc_title" type="text" value={this.state.inputVal}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

call from parent:

```
 <DocumentTitle publication={this.props.publication} />
```

Comment: it looks ok. if you have an ajax call, then redux is quite handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If publication is maintained in the parent, then there is no need to maintain state, unless there are other reasons: validations for one.

The input could be an uncontrolled component. The onBlur of the input can be used to update the parent.

```
<input 
  onBlur={e => this.props.onTitleChange(e.target.value)}
  id="doc_title" 
  type="text" 
  defaultValue={this.props.publication.document_title} />
```

The parent component should update the publication state.

```
<DocumentTitle 
  publication={this.state.publication} 
  onTitleChange={this.handleTitleChange} />
```

Comment: What if I need validation? What if props are coming from store?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `autocomplete` property of the `<input />`-component

```
<input
   autoComplete="phone"
   type="text"
   value={phone}
   onChange={(e) => {
      setPhone(e.target.value);
      }}
/>
```

Other autoComplete values are `name, email, organization,....`